# Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException

Tags: c#, xamarin

Estou criando um projeto Xamarin para estudo, tenho uma MasterPage e dentro dela tenho o código a baixo:

Estou compilando para o Android e vejo que o problema esta nesta linha:

```
xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:MyOrders.Pages;assembly=MyOrders"
```

Caso queira baixar o projeto que estou usando para estudo
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-svO0-4L_-Nb3I3MVZpTndQWms/view?usp=sharing

Erro:

> Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: Position 11:6. Type
>   MasterDetailpage not found in xmlns
>   http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:MyOrders.Pages;assembly=MyOrders"
             x:Class="MyOrders.Pages.MasterPage">


  <MasterDetailpage.Master>

    <!--menu da aplicação-->
    <pages:MenuPage>

    </pages:MenuPage>

  </MasterDetailpage.Master>



    <MasterDetailPage.Detail>

      <!--navegação da aplicação-->
      <NavigationPage x:Name="Navigator">

        <x:Arguments>
          <!--corpo da aplicação-->
          <pages:MainPage>

          </pages:MainPage>

        </x:Arguments>

      </NavigationPage>

    </MasterDetailPage.Detail>

</MasterDetailPage>
```

No código dela .cs tenho:

```html
namespace MyOrders.Pages
{
    public partial class MasterPage : MasterDetailPage
    {
        public MasterPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            App.Navigator = this.Navigator;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

MasterDetailpage está com o 'p' minúsculo.
O certo seria MasterDetailPage com 'P' maiúsculo :)